# Generated $\sigma$-algebra's containing countable subset with a specific element

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

During my exam for Introduction to Measure Theory, I came across the following question:

> Let $G$ be an arbitrary collection of subsets of some set $X$. Show that for a given $A \in \sigma(G)$ there exists a countable subcollection $G_A$ of $G$ depending in $A$, such that $A \in \sigma(G_A)$.

We have that $\sigma(G)$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by a set $G$. I was not able to figure out the answer to this question during the exam, but based on discussion with my peers afterwards, it seemed like the answer would be something like:

> All elements of a generated $\sigma$-algebra can always be written as countable combination of unions, complements and disjunctions of elements from the orignal set. Pick one such way of writing it, and then take $G_A$ the set off all these elements. Then $A \in \sigma(G_a)$ and $G_a$ is countable.

However, the truth of this first statement (All elements [...] from the original set) is not immediately clear to me. Is this actually the correct answer, and can someone make clear to me why this would be true?

Comment: How do you construct a $\sigma$-algebra from a collection of sets?

Comment: For us it is defined as the intersection of all $\sigma$-algebra's containing this collection of sets. The exact definition is: Given $G$ a collection of sets, the set $\sigma(G) = \cap_{j}\{A_j \mid G \subset A_j, A_j \text{ is a $\sigma$-algebra}\}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $G$.

Comment: It is not possible to write down all sets in the  generated sigma algebra explictly using countable unions, complements etc.  A totally wrong proof has been suggested  to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer provided above is wrong. Here is the correct way to prove it:

Consider the collection of all sets $A$ belonging to $\sigma (G)$ such that $A$ also belongs to the $\sigma$-algebra generated by some countable sub-collection of $G$. Verify that this is a $\sigma$-algebra and every element of $G$ belongs to it. Now do you see how to finish?

Comment: Ah I see, this collection of sets must be equal to $\sigma(G)$, and since in this set each element can be written as a countable union of elements of $G$, this can always be done. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see why $G \subset \{ A \in \sigma(G): A \in \sigma(G_A) \}$, e.g. when $G_A = \cup_{i=1}^n g_i \subsetneq G$. I mean, I can't see that $\sigma(G_A)$ will be large enough to include $G$ as a subset. Care to explain why it must be so?

Comment: @harisf If $A$ bleongs to $G$ then it is the union of the singlelton family $\{A\}$.